# Incorrect signal from signal generator H11887 DDS

Tags: signal, dds

I'm a newbie in engineering. I bought this generator on ali and built it.

Problem in signal from DDS out: it has incorrect form. I don't have +/- power supply so tested only on +5V.

Reasons could be:

- I made a mistake: put wrong resistor or something else.
- There is bad component: capacitor or resistor.
- +/-12V could affect signal form
- Wrong firmware on chip

How can I find problem?

I can provide more pictures - low reputation here.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Square wave looks good.. Sine wave is pretty bad looking.  Have you access somehow to a +/-12V or +/-5V to see if there is a difference in your signals?

Comment: If the unit is [specified to require three power supplies](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Professional-DDS-Function-Signal-Generator-Module-DIY-Kit-Sine-Square-Sawtooth-Triangle-Wave/32416482762.html), why did you think that it would do anything useful with only one of them hooked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+/-12V affect signal form.

You can check firmware and R–2R resistor ladder without +/-12V if connect an oscilloscope to R3 or 2pin OP-AMP.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! You absolutly right!